# Mapping two integers into one integer in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, mapping

I would like to map two integers into one for **hash** function in class. Those integers range from 0 to 12856320000000. I have heard that I can use the below Cantour pairing function to do so

[image]

However, my `sys.maxsize` is

```
9223372036854775807
```

As a result, when k1 and k2 are large as the following example, the answer will not be integer

```
k1 = 6887309306
k2 = 6887309307
pi(k1,k2)=9.487005898057764e+19
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: use `long` ints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused not by the number, but by the fact that you divide by 2. Division in Python 3.x always produces a floating point number. You should use integer division:

```
(k1 + k2) * (k1 + k2 + 1) // 2 + k2
#94870058980577640498
```